# How to use aurelia cli some features in skeleton-typescript-webpack?

Tags: webpack, aurelia

I clone an aurelia [skeleton-typescript-webpack](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-typescript-webpack) project. Is it possible at least to use aurelia cli `au generate` and maybe `au import` with webpack configuration?

Answer (score 1):

This really isn't possible at the current time. The current version of the CLI only works with the RequireJS based projects it creates. In the future, you'll be able to create a Webpack based project with the CLI.

Comment: How far is the near feature? I'm sure it's awesome for developer experience.

Comment: We don't have an ETA currently, but as we finish up bug fixes on the new Webpack skeleton, we should be moving to this next.

Comment: Hope it will come soon, as it will greatly improved bundling and enabling the use of HMR.